# Why is there a memory leak when calling `g_bus_get_sync` in GLib?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, glib

I've got the following code that I've compiled and ran through **Valgrind** but `g_bus_get_sync` seems to leak memory. Have I done something wrong?

```
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <libmm-glib.h>

static gboolean loop_ready(GMainLoop *loop)
{
    g_main_loop_quit(loop);
    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    g_autoptr(GDBusConnection)  connection = NULL;
    g_autoptr(GError)           error = NULL;

    connection = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, &error);
    if (!connection) {
        g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
    }

    // EDIT: Added g_dbus_connection_close_sync at suggestion of @user7860670
    g_dbus_connection_close_sync(connection);
    g_clear_object(&connection);

    {
        g_autoptr(GMainLoop) loop = NULL;

        loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
        g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)loop_ready, loop);
        g_main_loop_run(loop);
    }
}
```

Valgrind command `valgrind --tool=memcheck --suppressions=/usr/share/glib-2.0/valgrind/glib.supp --leak-check=full ./memtest`

Valgrind results:

```
==178041== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==178041== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==178041== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==178041== Command: ./memtest
==178041== 
==178041== 
==178041== HEAP SUMMARY:
==178041==     in use at exit: 104,240 bytes in 1,190 blocks
==178041==   total heap usage: 2,299 allocs, 1,109 frees, 238,311 bytes allocated
==178041== 
==178041== 304 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 946 of 969
==178041==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==178041==    by 0x40147D9: calloc (rtld-malloc.h:44)
==178041==    by 0x40147D9: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:375)
==178041==    by 0x40147D9: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:634)
==178041==    by 0x4EC4834: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:430)
==178041==    by 0x4EC4834: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.34 (pthread_create.c:647)
==178041==    by 0x4B53504: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x4B2ECCC: g_thread_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x4AFF616: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x49207D7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x4920884: g_task_get_type (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x498C288: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x4980020: g_bus_get_sync (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x1093AE: main (memtest.cpp:15)
==178041== 
==178041== 304 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 947 of 969
==178041==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==178041==    by 0x40147D9: calloc (rtld-malloc.h:44)
==178041==    by 0x40147D9: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:375)
==178041==    by 0x40147D9: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:634)
==178041==    by 0x4EC4834: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:430)
==178041==    by 0x4EC4834: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.34 (pthread_create.c:647)
==178041==    by 0x4B53504: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x4B2ECCC: g_thread_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x49762D9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x497FFF3: g_bus_get_sync (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4)
==178041==    by 0x1093AE: main (memtest.cpp:15)
==178041== 
==178041== LEAK SUMMARY:
==178041==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==178041==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==178041==      possibly lost: 608 bytes in 2 blocks
==178041==    still reachable: 64,442 bytes in 533 blocks
==178041==         suppressed: 26,374 bytes in 533 blocks
==178041== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==178041== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==178041== 
==178041== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
```

Comment: It this a "C" or "C++" question? It cannot be both at the same time (two different languages)

Comment: The function `g_bus_get_sync` returns a `GDBusConnection *`, now read the documentation I am sure you have to release that by yourself (maybe by calling delete or a cleanup function). A more modern C++ api should have returned an RAII object.

Comment: Careful reading [tag:C] *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: @PepijnKramer @273 - Although C and C++ is distinct I haven't used anything in my sample code that is C or C++ specific. It should work across both languages so unless I am mistaken it should compile across languages.

@PepinnKramer - I did read the documentation for glib, it says that [g_autoptr](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#g-autoptr) provides automatic cleanup when the variable goes out of scope. I've also used `g_clear_object` so it should unreference even without going out of scope.

Comment: ¿Don't you need to close opened connection with `g_dbus_connection_close_sync` prior to disposing? @PepijnKramer OP seem to be already using RAII and even forces object to be released in advance when invoking `g_clear_object(&connection);`

Comment: @user7860670: Doesn't seem to have helped, still leaking memory according to `valgrind`. Thanks for the catch though.

Comment: The memory is allocated when a thread is created. does glib do a `join()`? If it's detached then I would expect leaks - there's no way to clean up from detached threads.

Comment: And ltrace might tell you if the thread is created detached.

Comment: @user7860670 That's why I said read the documentation :) I have no experience with this api but from the call returning a raw pointer + memory leak it was clear something needed to be done :)

Comment: Valgrind says 0 bytes are definitely lost. Without a valgrind trace with debug symbols for libgio.so, it’s not possible to say where the possible leak is coming from or whether it’s actually a real leak. It looks like a background task thread which is not joined before the process exits, which is not a big deal — in a longer running process, that thread probably would be joined soon enough. Your code looks fine.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall in Valgrind when we say `posssible leak` we don't mean that it is vaguely possible, we mean that it is almost certainly a leak but we're not 100% sure that it's not really a kind of `reachable`. If the thread is created detached then it would be an error to join() it. The leaks is harmless if it is just a couple of 304 byte blocks.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: The [ltrace output](https://pastebin.com/VQtbX0hq) is out of my depth but nothing seems to jump out at me.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: GLib doesn’t consider `reachable` memory as a leak.